# Trying to pop-up window that contains a form, but form not shown - extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to display a pop-up window that contains a form in extjs 5, using django-rest as backend. I manage to get the pop-up window shown, but the form inside it is not shown. If I put just an html tag instead of the form, the tag contents are shown. I am very confused as I can't make it work to show the form. Any help would be so much appreciated. The codes are:

- Controller:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Manage', {
 
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
 
 views: ['Manage'],
 
 // controller initialisation
 init: function() {
 
  // save scope
  var manageController = this;
  
  console.log('manage controller started');
  
  // instanciate view class but hide initially
  this.view = this.getView('Manage').create().hide();
  
  // Request manage variables (lastDayUpd)
  Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/api/manage/',
   method: 'GET',
   
   success: function(response, options){
    
    console.log('got last day upd');
    
    // Decode response
    var res = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText).results[0].lastDayUpd;
    console.log(res);
    
    // Get manage panel from container
    var cp = (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('container#manageContentPanel')[0]).getComponent('lastDayUpd');
    
    // Set data to display last day updated
    cp.setConfig('html', ('Last day updated: '+res));
   },
   failure: function(response, options) {
    console.log('not got last day upd');
   }
  });
   
  this.control({
   
   // register for the logout-click
   '#logoutButton': {
    click: function() {
    
     // mask the complete viewport
     this.view.mask('Logout…')
     
     // ask the login-controller to perform the logout in the backend
     MyApp.getApplication().getController('Login').performLogout(function(success) {
      
      if(!success) {
       // return WITHOUT unmasking the main app, keeping the app unusable
       return Ext.Msg.alert('Logout failed', 'Close and restart the Application')
      }
      
      // unmask and hide main viewport and all content
      this.view.unmask();
      this.view.hide();
      
      // relaunch application
      MyApp.getApplication().launch();
     });
    }
   },
   
   // register for click in the navigation tree
   '#navTree': {
    itemclick: function(tree, node) {
     // ignore clicks on group nodes
     // TODO: pass click on to first sub-item
     // ignore clicks on non-leave nodes (groups)
     if(!node.data.leaf) 
      return;
     // pass the id of the clicked node to the content-panel
     // enable the corresponding content view
     this.getContentPanel().setActiveItem(node.data.itemId);
    }
   },
   
   // Show update form to perform update
   '#updButton': {
    click: function(){
     //alert('Clicked');
     //navigationController.getController('Manage').view.show()
     this.showUpdateForm();
    }
   }
  });  
 },
 
 showUpdateForm: function(){
  
  // Get manage panel from container
  var form = (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('container#manageContentPanel')[0]).getComponent('updateDaskalosBox').show();
  
  console.log('form is:');
  console.log(form); 
  console.log('show update form');;
 },
});
```

- View:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Manage', {
 
 layout: 'border',
 extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
 renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
 id: "manageContainer",
 
 // todo: not resizing correctly
 width: '100%',
 height: '100%',
 
 items: [{
    region: 'west',
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    itemId: 'navTree',
    width: 150,
    split: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    title: 'Navigation',
    tbar: [
     { text: 'Logout', itemId: 'logoutButton' }
    ]
   },
   {
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'container',
    itemId: 'manageContentPanel',
    layout: {
     type: 'border',
     //columns: 3,
     //deferredRender: true
    },
    
    items: [
     {
      itemId: 'lastDayUpd',
      title: 'Manage Daskalos', 
      xtype: 'panel',
      
      buttons: [
       {
        text: 'Update',
        itemId: 'updButton'
       },
       {
        text: 'Back',
        itemId: 'backButton',
       }
      ],
      
      html: 'Last Day Updated: ' 
     },
     {
      xtype: 'messagebox',
      itemId: 'updateDaskalosBox',
      layout: 'fit',
      title: 'Update daskalos',
      //html: 'A pop up',
      //floating: true,
      //closable : true,
      
      items: [
       { 
        xtype: 'panel',
        itemId: 'updateDaskalosPanel',
        //layout: 'fit',
        
        items: [
         {
          xtype: 'form',
          itemId: 'updateDaskalosForm',
          //url: '', // to fill
          layout: 'fit',
         
          //renderTo: 'updateForm',
    
          fieldDefaults: {
           labelAlign: 'left',
           labelWidth: 100
          },
          
          buttons: [
           {
            text: 'Update',
            itemId: 'updButton',
            formBind: true,
           },
           {
            text: 'Cancel',
            itemId: 'cancelButton',
           }
          ],
          
          items: [
                                             //Just one field for now to see if it works
           //{
            //xtype: 'datefield',
            ////anchor: '100%',
            //fieldLabel: 'From',
            ////name: 'from_date',
            ////maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
           //},
           {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'last',
            allowBlank: false
           }       
          ],
         },
        ],
       },
      ],
     },
    ]
   }
 ],
});
```

After controller initialization, I want when the user clicks the update button to pop up a window that contains a form to post data to the server. The pop-up is thrown, but the form inside the panel that the window contains as child item seems that has the problem. Does anyone see what I miss here?

Thanks for the help! Babis.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just create a window containing a form? Your "pop-up window" is a messagebox, that you abuse. There is also no need to put a form in a panel. A form extends from panel.

// you have some trailing commas in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.Manage', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.manage',
    requires: ['Ext.form.Panel'],
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    layout: 'fit',
    resizable: false,
    autoShow: true,
    animCollapse:false,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            /*
             *
             * Start you code for form
             */
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

You want a form in a window, but can you tell why are you extending container ??